# Seamless video loop with VideoView without lagging

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In this application, we want to display consecutive videos without any delay in viewing.  The uri for each video were stored inside an array, and through looping we displayed these videos, but there was a delay in the presentation between the video and the other. How can this problem be solved?

```
public class ShowActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

VideoView video;
ProgressDialog pd;
int currentPlayingIndex = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show);
    video=findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    pd=new ProgressDialog(ShowActivity.this);

    Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
    String[] arrayresulturi=b.getStringArray("uriresult");

    video=findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(arrayresulturi[0]);
    video.setVideoURI(uri);
    video.start();

    video.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            currentPlayingIndex++;
            if (arrayresulturi[currentPlayingIndex] != null) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(arrayresulturi[currentPlayingIndex]);
                video.setVideoURI(uri);
                video.start();

            }// end if()
            else {
                video.stopPlayback();
                Intent backIntent = new Intent(ShowActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(backIntent);
            }//end else
        }//end onCompletion
    });//end setOnCompletionListener()
}//end onCreate()
```

}//end class

Comment: I assume the delay comes from loading the player of the next video? You could try preloading the player in some way before the first video ends. Btw, I wouldn't put these comments behind your closing brackets. It should be obvious from the indentation where which code block ends.

Comment: @JohannesMols  Do you Know away  to preloading the player before the first video ends??